# i am searching from two columns of one table using this query but this not working

Tags: mysql

I am searching from two columns of one table usning this query but this not working

Here is my Query :

```
 $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM share_experience 
            WHERE (`content1` LIKE '%".$query."%')||
            (`option1` LIKE '%".$query."%')&&(`option1` LIKE '%".$topic."%')";
```

Comment: Use OR instead of || and AND instead of &&

Comment: An **not working** means what exactly? You need to ask clear questions so we can help you. Edit your question and explain what you want to achieve, and issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `count(*)` which will always return only one value.
You should use a union to get both results:

```
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM share_experience 
            WHERE (`content1` LIKE '%".$query."%')
            UNION
            SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM share_experience
            WHERE (`option1` LIKE '%".$query."%') AND (`option1` LIKE '%".$topic."%')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the issue you're facing, but try this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM share_experience 
           WHERE content1 LIKE '%".$query."%') OR
           (option1 LIKE '%".$query."%' AND option1 LIKE '%".$topic."%')";
```